# SQL query filter issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a query filter that is not returning correct data...
This is to pull out news articles for a site homepage listing. I have a field called HideFromHome (boolean) which I'm trying to filter, as well as publish and remove dates:

```
$today=date('Y-m-d');   
$filter = "HideFromHome != 1 AND ";
$filter .= "((PublishDate <= '".$today."') AND (RemoveDate > '".$today."')) OR ";
$filter .= "((PublishDate IS NULL AND RemoveDate > '".$today."')) OR "; 
$filter .= "((PublishDate <= '".$today."' AND RemoveDate IS NULL)) OR ";
$filter .= "((PublishDate IS NULL AND RemoveDate IS NULL))";
```

everything works fine except it is returning all articles, even with HideFromHome selected...can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Please post the MySQL query that this code generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more parentheses. Each of those 'OR's is on the same level as the first 'AND'
try:

```
$today=date('Y-m-d');   
$filter = "HideFromHome != 1 AND (";
$filter .= "((PublishDate <= '".$today."') AND (RemoveDate > '".$today."')) OR ";
$filter .= "((PublishDate IS NULL AND RemoveDate > '".$today."')) OR "; 
$filter .= "((PublishDate <= '".$today."' AND RemoveDate IS NULL)) OR ";
$filter .= "((PublishDate IS NULL AND RemoveDate IS NULL)))";
```

as explained by H-Man2's answer `FALSE AND TRUE OR TRUE` is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

You may need parentheses around the or parts, because `false and true or true` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try `HideFromHome <> 1`.
`!=` ("not-equal") is `<>` ("less-or-greater") for MySQL.